# Titanium The network connection was lost

Tags: ios7, sdk, titanium, titanium-mobile, ios7.1

When I hit the below url

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=hkj&components=country:gb&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDW17njzyRkeCkpDjbvIMSZGNcioniphYo

I am getting following error on Titanium SDK 3.3.0

[INFO] : code = "-1005"; [INFO] : error = "The network connection was lost."; [INFO] : source = "[object TiNetworkHTTPClient]"; [INFO] : success = 0; [INFO] : type = error; Same url is working on Titanium SDK 3.1.3

Other url's are working fine with both SDK's